# buffer manipulation in c

Tags: c, buffer

Newbie question.I am trying to extract a part of a buffer in C.

```
char temp[50];
strcpy(temp,"local@192.168.1.123<>morestringshere");
```

I want to extract the IP only from this buffer and save the ip. One important point is that every buffer might contain different user name such as "local" with varying length of the user name.Is there a simple way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: Read about [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser). But your question is too broad, does not show any effort, so will be closed. Look into [regexp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). And you need to formalize the possible inputs (e.g. with [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)).

Comment: `sscanf` it! Read and discard everythin until a `@`. Then, read and store everything until a `<`.

Comment: Also `strchr()` might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sscanf` as follows

```
sscanf(temp,"%*[^@]%*c%[^<]",ip);
```

This will discard string until `'@'` and then discard `'@`' and will store the string into *char array* `ip` until `'<`'` is encountered . Thus you will get your ip.

Comment: This is pretty good, but I think `"%*[^@]@%16[0-9.]"` would be a bit better: (1) you can just match the `@`; (2) you should always specify a length limit on `%[` and `%s` conversions to avoid buffer overrun; (3) OP is not totally clear whether the IP number is terminated with `<>` but it is easy enough to terminate it when an illegal character is found. A more sophisticated pattern would be needed to restrict the ip to four dotted decimals, and you'd need to add `:a-fA-F` if you wanted to also recognize IPv6.

Comment: @rici  Yes Sir I agree with you ,restricting string to contain `%16[0-9.]` will be good and prevent overrun also .

Comment: @rici  SIr should I include it my answer ?

Comment: You're free to use the suggestion in your answer, if you feel it improves things.

Answer (score -1):

Sscanf should be able to extract ip easily